# Heirarchical UITableView effect like ios directory create

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How to create hierarchical UITableView? So if you move cell on cell it will create a tableview. Effect like in iOS create directory

Any ideas? May be you have some examples, share it!

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you just trying to create a hierarchical table, or do you really mean a directory of files, or a directory of people, or what?

Comment: I guess it is all about heirarchical UITableViews...

Comment: heirarchical table with effect like in ios (how to create directory)

Comment: See `NSFileManager` for methods to create a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by creating two UITableViewControllers, for example, `primaryViewController` and `detailViewController`. In `primaryViewController`'s .m file add logic for transition to `detailViewController`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
     DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```